# Discord bot has been flagged by our anti-spam system for abusive behavior. Bot is quarantined

Tags: javascript, python, discord.js

I tired to dm all of server members with the bot. After Dming 50 individual there is an API error calling, your bot has been flagged by our anti-spam system for abusive behavior and quarantined.
I do not know how to fix this so it would be great if anyone can help. I have tired both the python and JS languages. Do I need to give any delay or something to not go as spam?

Comment: Easy. Mass-DMs are not allowed from bots. I think it’s also not allowed from users too. This is considered API abuse and can get your bot banned. It’s best to message in a guild. You can’t take it out yet but they will eventually allow it again.

Answer (score 1):

Your bot is flagged. Look up to [this](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#global-rate-limit) You cant spam message people in discord read the [terms](https://discord.com/developers/docs/legal#section-1-acceptance-of-the-terms-and-registration) .I suggest you to try to open a new bot acc and use the new bot client token for your code for now.